# Reformat data through macro excel 2010?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, macros

I am trying to create a macro that allows me to change the data I received from a client into data I can import into a system. The data I receive is in the format:

[image]

How Can I do this through VBA Macro? So it should read the data, then create a new sheet with the copy of the data in the format I can use. Like this:

[image]

Comment: I know you asked for VBA, but FYI, a non-VBA solution is to use PowerQuery addon from Microsoft.  It has built-in unpivot functionality.

Comment: This example doesn't *look* like a **pivot table**. Is it in pivot table form or is it just in a structure that you'd like to modify?

Comment: It is in a structure that I want. Sorry it is not in Pivot format currently

Comment: How many columns (funds) are there?

Comment: There are any number of columns (funds). It will change on a monthly basis. As will the date range (rows).

Comment: SO it should read the data from the sheet the client gives me, creates a new sheet with the data in the format I need it in. And this data range will vary from month to month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the macro that should do what you want. It:

- Prompts for the number of funds
- Assumes the data table begins in `A1`
- prints on "Sheet2" in columns `A` through `C`
- Quits if it encounters an empty cell in the `date` column

***Note: if "Sheet2" doesn't exist, the macro will fail, so create it. Also you'll need to put headers onto "Sheet2" and adjust the cell format for dates and amounts in "Sheet2"***

#### adjust as needed

```
Sub wolfeline()
Dim c As Range
Dim k As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim WScurr As Worksheet
Dim WStarg As Worksheet

'Set current and target WS
'//Note: target WS must exist already
Set WScurr = ActiveSheet
Set WStarg = Sheets("Sheet2")

'k=2 so we start on row 2, below the headers you've put, adjust as needed
k = 2

'count the range of dates
y = [counta(A:A)]

'Ask user to input number of funds
x = InputBox("Number of Funds?")
'Feel free to define range("A:A") to your actual range e.g. range("A2:A100")
For Each c In WScurr.Range("A2:A" & y)
If c.Value = "" Then Exit Sub

    ' "to 3" indicates there are 3 funds, adjust as needed
    For i = 1 To x
        If c.Offset(, i) <> "" Then
            'we're printing this in columns K, L and M, adjust as needed
            WStarg.Cells(k, "A") = c
            WStarg.Cells(k, "B") = Cells(1, c.Offset(, i).Column)
            WStarg.Cells(k, "C") = c.Offset(, i)
            k = k + 1
        End If
    Next
Next


End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this, but what if it has an undefined amount of dates and funds? It will change monthly.

Comment: Change the macro to reflect the number of funds per month. You can just keep `range("A:A")` for the undetermined amount of dates.

Comment: Sorry @Raystafarian for my ignorance, but how do I change the macro for an undefined number of funds? and how do I change the macro to copy all this data to a new sheet starting with column A (Date), Column B (Named Fund) and Column C (Amount)?

Comment: @WolfeLine you asked for a macro so I figured you could adjust the macro as needed. See the new edit. The target is "sheet2" so change that if it's wrong. It prompts for the number of funds, you can't keep it undefined or it will run forever.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on the macro recorder and use the method found on John Walkenbach's blog. It comes up with this code using the sample data in your screenshot:

```
Sub Unpivot()

'
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlConsolidation, SourceData:= _
        Array("Sheet1!R1C1:R4C4"), Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15).CreatePivotTable _
        TableDestination:="", TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:= _
        xlPivotTableVersion15
    ActiveSheet.PivotTableWizard TableDestination:=ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 1)
    ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").DataPivotField.PivotItems( _
        "Count of Value").Position = 1
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Row").Orientation = _
        xlHidden
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Column").Orientation = _
        xlHidden
    Range("A4").Select
    Selection.ShowDetail = True
End Sub
```

Adjust to your liking or try the code John Walkenbach posts [here](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/creating_a_database_table_from_a_summary_table/). It has been written for an earlier version of Excel, so it may look different than 2010 code.

Comment: thank you teylyn, can i just ask what this is referring to? SourceData:= _
        Array("Sheet1!R1C1:R4C4")

Comment: It may help to note that there are a variable number of dates in Column A and a variable number of Funds in Row 1. I tried the above code but it gave me an error and debugging highlighted:  ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlConsolidation, SourceData:= _
        Array("Sheet1!R1C1:R4C4"), Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15).CreatePivotTable _
        TableDestination:="", TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:= _
        xlPivotTableVersion15

Comment: @WolfeLine it's failing because this macro assumes we're working with an actual pivot table, which, after clarification in the comments, is not the case.

Comment: I said that this code is based on your screenshot data sample and that you need to adjust it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have too many columns of funds, you can do it by hand.

1. In front of Fund 1 (Column B), insert one column.  Copy down an 'IF' formula to each cell that checks if there's a value in Column B (now Column C), and if so, sets the content to "Fund 1". That is, in cell B2:

   > =IF(C2<>"", "Fund 1", "")
2. In front of the next Fund column, insert two columns.  In the first of the two, set an 'IF' formula that checks if there is a value in the Fund column, and if so, copies the date from Column A.  In the second of the two new columns repeat the step 1 above, but insert the correct fund.  That is in cells D2 and E2

   > =IF(F2<>"", A2, "")        ||         =IF(F2<>"", "Fund 2", "") ||

Do this for each Fund Column.

3.  Then, copy the cells from each of the three-column blocks to a new sheet, so that each consecutive block is placed beneath the previous one.  That is, select and copy from the first data cell of Column A (not row 1) to the last cell with data in Column C - not the entire columns - and paste them in the top left cell of the new sheet. Then select and copy the data from the first cell in Column D, down to the last data cell in Column F, and paste it in Column A at the row immediately beneath the previously pasted data.

Once all these blocks have been copied, you can sort the data by Column A (the date column).  This will not only put all the transactions in chrono order, but also block all the blanks together, leaving you with data in the format you're looking for.

**Macro version**

If there *are* a lot of Fund Columns, use the macro recorder to do steps 1 and 2, and run  the code that does step 2 through a loop for each fund (set the "Fund #" string by doing some math on the column you are in).

Then do a similar macro recorder job to copy and paste the first couple of three column blocks and then sort them, and again, loop through the copy/past code for every Fund